# onClick change src images

Tags: javascript, onclick, src

I'm trying to do this [shema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7aJO.png) with JavaScript, when I click on the Switch button, it changes the car (.png) and the text content related to the car inside the sidebar (car specs), I have four cars.
(I'm a front-end junior dev, and still figure out how to manage this),

If you can give me few clues, it will help a lot !

thank you

my code HTML looks like this for the button :

```
<div class="btn" onclick="changeCar()"> <img id="img-id" src="/src/asset/img/pixel-yellow-car.png" alt=""> <span>SWITCH</span> </div>
```

---

hero section :

```
<div class="hero_car">
                        <div class=""><img id="hero-car-src" src="/src/asset/img/pixel-purple-car.png" alt=""></div>
                    </div>
```

car specs code :

```
<aside class="car-specs" id="img">
                    <div id="purple-car-specs">
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                POWER
                                <br>
                                425
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                WEIGHT
                                <br>
                                4,140
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                GRIP
                                <br>
                                135
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                SHIFT SPEED
                                <br>
                                0.350s
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="blue-car-specs">
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                POWER
                                <br>
                                425
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                WEIGHT
                                <br>
                                4,140
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                GRIP
                                <br>
                                135
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                SHIFT SPEED
                                <br>
                                0.350s
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="green-car-specs">
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                POWER
                                <br>
                                425
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                WEIGHT
                                <br>
                                4,140
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                GRIP
                                <br>
                                135
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                SHIFT SPEED
                                <br>
                                0.350s
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="yellow-car-specs">
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                POWER
                                <br>
                                425
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                WEIGHT
                                <br>
                                4,140
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                GRIP
                                <br>
                                135
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="div">
                            <span>
                                SHIFT SPEED
                                <br>
                                0.350s
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </aside>
```

Edit : Thanks to Devielu the onclick function is working with few tweaks, I'm now thinking about how to connect those car-specs to the right imgs.

Comment: Provide us with more details so we can help, for example how your code is looks like?

Comment: You could start by tracing the data flow: where is the data about a car coming from, how is it reaching the browser, what object structure is the data decoded into for use in JavasScript? etc. When you have this information consider asking a question about dealing with it if you need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an ID on your image element. Something like this:

```html
<img id="img-id" src="" onclick="changeCar()" />
```

Then you can create an array with your images path and an index to know which image is selected.

```js
var index = 0;
const images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png"];
```

After that you create your function changeCar that will update the image and increment the index. If the index equals to images.length, then will reset index to 0:

```js
function changeCar() {
  document.getElementById("img-id").src = images[index];
  index += 1;              
  if (index == images.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
}
```

Try to apply something like this and give your feedback.

Comment: I'm getting this error : imgIndex is not defined
    at changeCar

Comment: @B4D oh sorry. I already fixed it. You need to change imgIndex to index.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend !! It's working, I had to tweak few things, var index = 0; instead of const index =0; , .src = images[index++], and index == images.length +1 instead of -1, -1 don't display one of the 4 images, but when I put +1 it shows each imgs it's perfect but will also display a blank src, I'm trying to fix that. Thanks again for the help !!

Comment: When I wrote the code I didn't test it.. I just wanted to give you an idea. I already fix the answer.